# Unexpected indent error while i break my url to short length as per PEP8 guideline

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation, pep8

I tried to make url of short length but its giving unexpected indent.i provided the piece of code on which its giving error

trackback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\movie trailer\entertainment.py", line 1, in 
   
    import media
   File "C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\movie trailer\media.py", line 85
    "/w185"+str(detail_new[4])"
    ^
   IndentationError: unexpected indent

```
self.poster_image_url = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p"
                                "/w185"+str(detail_new[4])"
self.trailer_youtube_url = 
                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?"
                    "v="+str(self.get_trailer_link(movie_name))"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "\" to indicate to Python that the line does not terminate:

```
my_variable = "beginning of the string" \
              "end of the string"
```

For your second case:

```
my_variable = \
  "beginning of the string" \
  "end of the string"
```

You can also use parentheses for the same purpose:

```
my_variable = (
  "beginning of the string"
  "end of the string"
)
```

For your specific case:

```
self.poster_image_url = (
  'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p'
  '/w185' + str(detail_new[4])
)
self.trailer_youtube_url = (
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?'
  'v=' + str(self.get_trailer_link(movie_name))
)
```

Comment: while using parenthesis i get SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: That's because of your malformed string `"v="+str(self.get_trailer_link(movie_name))"` (there shouln't be a " at the end)

Comment: while using "\" getting invalid syntax

Comment: Same reason ;-) I updated my answer, so you can copy&paste if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.poster_image_url = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p  \
                                         /w185+str({0})])".format(detail_new[4])

self.trailer_youtube_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?" \
                                               "v=" + "str({0})".format(self.get_trailer_link(movie_name))
```